# How to customize TimePicker in material design android?

Tags: android, android-theme, android-timepicker

I am unable to change the selector color and other parts of the TimePicker.
So far, I can change header color and background but I am unable to change the innercircle and the textcolor.

Change custom theme [link](https://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_4/material_ext_publish/0B3321sZLoP_HcVRNejI4UTh6aHM/components_pickers_time1.png).

My code :

```
<TimePicker
    android:id="@+id/tp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:timePickerMode="clock"
    android:headerBackground="#565466"
    android:amPmBackgroundColor="#500126"
    android:numbersBackgroundColor="#57e326"
    android:numbersTextColor="#995394"
    android:numbersSelectorColor="#675543"
    android:textColorSecondary="#897530"
    android:textColorPrimary="#359875"
/>
```

Comment: Which fields should I add/edit in style resources ?

Comment: @Heyyou Sorry, I didn't saw it. It put it back! :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

#### Basic mode

All you have to do is set your accent color in your Activity's theme:

```
<item name="colorAccent">#3333cc</item>
```

This will set all the colors for you so you wouldn't mess up the styling.

(*This also means that you shouldn't set values like `amPmBackgroundColor` on your TimePicker directly, let Android do the things for you.*)

#### Advanced mode

If you want to specify all the possible values separately, do the following:

First define this in your Activity's theme:

```
<item name="android:timePickerStyle">@style/Theme.MyTheme.TimePicker</item>
```

Then create the appropriate style:

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme.TimePicker" parent="android:Widget.Material.Light.TimePicker">
    <item name="android:timePickerMode">clock</item>
    <item name="android:headerBackground">#ff555555</item>
    <item name="android:numbersTextColor">?android:attr/textColorPrimaryActivated</item>
    <item name="android:numbersInnerTextColor">?android:attr/textColorSecondaryActivated</item>
    <item name="android:numbersSelectorColor">?android:attr/colorControlActivated</item>
    <item name="android:numbersBackgroundColor">#ff555555</item>
    <item name="android:amPmTextColor">?android:attr/textColorSecondary</item>
</style>
```

Note that `numbersInnerTextColor` is only available from API level 23 and other styles (e.g. `headerTextColor`) can't be set (or at least I couldn't make it work).

I'd advise against using the "advanced" mode as the TimePicker should have the same colors as the containing Activity and doing otherwise might impact your UX in a bad way.

Comment: How can I customize each one of those elements ??

Comment: Thanks Gergely. I will get back if I have more Q.

Comment: I am unable to change background color of ok and cancel buttons layout .The view below numbers . Background color is not changing the layout below .How can I change the color ? Thanks

Comment: That styling is handled by the Activity's theme, specifically by the AlertDialog and Dialog styles.

Comment: how to change this if android:timePickerMode="spinner" ?

Answer (score 7):

TimePicker material style:

**TimePickerDialog material style with custom colors**

```
<style name="MyTimePickerDialogStyle" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert">
<item name="showTitle">false</item>
<item name="colorControlActivated">#ffd600</item>
<item name="colorAccent">#b71c1c</item>
<item name="android:textColorPrimary">#43a047</item>
<item name="android:textColorSecondary">#f44336</item>
</style>
```

**TimePicker widget style**

```
<style name="MyTimePickerWidgetStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.TimePicker">
    <item name="android:headerBackground">#ffe082</item>
    <item name="android:numbersTextColor">#b71c1c</item>
    <item name="android:numbersInnerTextColor">#f44336</item>
    <item name="android:numbersSelectorColor">#33691e</item>
    <item name="android:numbersBackgroundColor">#ef9a9a</item>
    <item name="android:amPmTextColor">#9c27b0</item>
</style>
```

For more information on TimePicker see http://www.zoftino.com/android-timepicker-example

Comment: For anyone looking: overwrite "Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog" for compatability.

Answer (score 1):

For material 3 design you have to use the following attributes to change the colors and use

```
<style name="ThemeOverlay.PChart.Material3TimePicker" parent="ThemeOverlay.Material3.MaterialTimePicker">
    <item name="colorSurface">@color/white_fade</item>
    <item name="colorOnSurfaceVariant">@color/darkCyan</item>
    <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/gray_faded_AA</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/darkCyan</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimaryContainer">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryContainer">@color/darkCyan</item>
</style>
```

and in kotlin code

```
val picker =
        MaterialTimePicker.Builder()
            .setTheme(R.style.ThemeOverlay_PChart_Material3TimePicker)
            .setInputMode(INPUT_MODE_CLOCK)
            .setTimeFormat(TimeFormat.CLOCK_24H)
            .setHour(initialHour)
            .setMinute(initialMinute)
            .setTitleText(title)
            .build()
```